# Should I use a key with a fragment or better not to use fragments in this case?

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a timeline like this one: https://codepen.io/brady_wright/pen/NNOvrW

Here's my React code

```
  <ul className={`${styles.timeline} ${styles.timelineSplit}`}>
     {/* year of the first event in the array */}      
     <li className={`${styles.timelineItem} ${styles.period}`} key={history[0].year}>
        <h2 className={styles.timelineTitle}>{history.year}</h2>
      </li>
    
      {history.map((h, index) => (
        <>
          {/* if current year is not equal to the year of the next event then I show the year between those 2 events */}
          {index - 1 >= 0 && history[index].year !== history[index - 1].year && (
            <li className={`${styles.timelineItem} ${styles.period}`} key={h.year}>
              <h2 className={styles.timelineTitle}>{history[index].year}</h2>
            </li>
          )}
    
          <li className={styles.timelineItem} key={h.id}>
            <h3 className={styles.timelineTitle}>{h.header}</h3>
          </li>
        </>
      ))}
    </ul>
```

The problem is React wants me to use a key for every fragment. To me it seems a bit weird. I understand that every fragment needs a key since they are created inside `.map()` but... wrapping a year and the event itself into a fragment and use a key with it seems to be redundant since the year is not going to be added in every iteration. Maybe once in 10 iterations.

The question is what is a better solution for showing a year? Or should I keep the code as it is and give every fragment a key? And what should I use as a key for a fragment btw?

Comment: Whats the harm to use key? I feel adding key inside a map is the best practice. It might not be possible with the short version of fragment but I would recommend using `key`.

Comment: The key is what react uses internally to make sure it knows what to update. So if you don't supply a key and state is updated it might not work correctly without keys. If you have a unique identifier, use that. Doesn't matter what it is. You can combine multiple fields to a unique key if needed. Or fall back to using indexes as a last resort.

Comment: React docs recommend the use of [keyed fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments). The correct placement in this example would be to remove the keys from both of the `li` elements and instead write `<React.Fragment key={h.id}>`.

Comment: @super but a fragment in fact is just a trick and will not be added to a DOM-tree. Why does it have to have a key then?